# setonclicklistener for ratingbar and imagebutton

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ratingbar, android-imagebutton

I'm doing a class project and am stuck here.

Scenario: When I tap on Add button, info entered on this form will be saved in the database. The form has 3 editText, 1 imageButton and 1 ratingBar.

Problem: how do I code for imageButton and ratingBar in OnClick?

```
btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //how to add this part for imageButton1 and ratingBar1?
            String title = ((EditText) 
                    findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
            String date = ((EditText) 
                    findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
            String review = (String) ((EditText) 
                    findViewById(R.id.editText3)).getText().toString();

Book newBook = new Book(0, image, title, date, rating, review);

            Books i = new Books(BookActivity.this);

            i.addBook(newBook);
```

This is my DB portion:

```
public void addBook(byte[] image, String title, String date, float rating, String review) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();     
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    values.put(COL_IMAGE, image);
    values.put(COL_TITLE, title);
    values.put(COL_DATE, date);
    values.put(COL_RATING, rating);
    values.put(COL_REVIEW, review);
    db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, null, values);
    db.close();
```

Comment: What's the problem you getting with this code.

Comment: How to add the code for imagebutton and ratingbar in the onClick method

Comment: you want to retrieve the image from image view and ratings from rating bar am right.

Comment: yes correct. i learnt how to retrieve strings, but i'm not sure how to retrieve image and rating..

Comment: for storing image in database you need to store it as a byteArray in a field with type BLOB,

Comment: check this link rating bar:  http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/

Comment: @Nurayn Can you tell your issue??

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Rating Bar Value

```
ratingBar.getRating() ; //GET RATING BAR VALUE
```

For image from ImageView

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)yourimageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if it should be as simple as the following:

For ImageButton:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageButton.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

(Be carefull to check if your image.getDrawable() can actually be cast to BitmapDrawable (to avoid IllegalCastExceptions))

For RatingBar:

```
float ratingText=ratingBar.getRating();
int numberOfStars=ratingBar.getNumStars();
```